# Building vdproj via devenv.com doesn't pack all dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, vdproj

I'm developing a plugin (C# dll) in VS2019, and I need installer project. Since ClickOnce is not available for dlls, I had to resort to old Windows Installer (vdproj).
So far so good.

The catch is: if I build it by hand, from IDE, everthing is fine, I can see that all dependencies are packaged in:

```
<...>
Packaging file 'System.Buffers.dll'...
Packaging file 'FontAwesome.WPF.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.ValueTuple.dll'...
Packaging file 'PowerMillExporterPlugin.dll'...
Packaging file 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll'...
Packaging file 'Newtonsoft.Json.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.Net.Http.dll'...
Packaging file 'Swan.Lite.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.Memory.dll'...
Packaging file 'NLog.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.Text.Json.dll'...
Packaging file 'ByteSize.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.Net.Http.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll'...
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

However, if I build it from console with `devenv.com`: `devenv.com .\PowerMillExporterPlugin.sln /rebuild "Debug|Any CPU" .\Setup\Setup.vdproj` only one dependency (and my dll) are packaged:

```
Packaging file 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll'...
Packaging file 'PowerMillExporterPlugin.dll.config'...
Packaging file 'PowerMillExporterPlugin.dll'...
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Why is that? Build configuration is the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by ditching old Windows Installer and using WixSharp instead.